# Passing data from text field to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting error in ToDoViewController.Swift here is the overall code:
I am makeing a simple app for taking orders from customers. and orders will store in Firebase.

**View Controller.Swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var todoList = [Todo]()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        self.todoList.removeAll()
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("todoList").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let todoDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                for (_,todoElement) in todoDict {
                    print(todoElement);
                    let todo = Todo()
                    todo.name = todoElement["name"] as? String
                    todo.message = todoElement["message"] as? String
                    todo.reminderDate = todoElement["date"] as? String
                    self.todoList.append(todo)
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    //MARK: TableView datasource

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.todoList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoCell")
        cell!.textLabel?.text = todoList[indexPath.row].name
        return cell!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
}
```

**ToDoViewController**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ToDoViewController: UIViewController {

    var todo:Todo?

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateFormatter: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func Done(_ sender: Any) {
        if todo == nil {
            todo = Todo()
        }

        // first section
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"

        todo?.name = self.nameField.text
        todo?.message = self.messageField.text
        todo?.reminderDate = dateFormatter.string(from: self.dateFormatter.date)

        //second section
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let key = ref.child("todoList").childByAutoId().key

        let dictionaryTodo = [ "name"    : todo!.name! ,
                               "message" : todo!.message!,
                               "date"    : todo!.reminderDate!]

        let childUpdates = ["/todoList/\(key)": dictionaryTodo]
        ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) -> Void in
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let todoVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToDoVC") as! ToDoViewController
        todoVC.todo = todoList[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(todoVC, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if self.todo != nil {
            nameField.text = self.todo?.name
            messageField.text = self.todo?.message
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self.todo!.reminderDate!)
            datePicker.date = date!
        }
    }
}
```

**Todo.Swift**

```
import UIKit
class Todo: NSObject {
    var name :String?
    var message: String?
    var reminderDate: String?
    // id which is set from firebase to uniquely identify it
    var uniqueId:String?
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your code:

1. `Use of un-resolved identifier 'todoList'`:

`todoList` is declared in `View Controller.Swift` and you cannot use it in `ToDoViewController`.

2. `Cannot assign to property: 'date' is a method`:

In the code `datePicker` is undefined and `@IBOutlet weak var dateFormatter: UIDatePicker!` should be:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

AND In the image `dateFormatter.date = date!` should be:

```
datePicker.date = date!
```